# Large switch statement or scatter with a virtual void

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I've been rewritting some of the old code lines and classes I had in an application that I'm writting and right now I'm trying to decide if I shall touch this one or leave it as it is.

So currently I've got a class that's basically running on a single thread and is called constantly returning different results. The class basically relies on a switch statement that chooses what to do considering the information given to it.

Here's what I'm having trouble deciding. The switch statement has over 300 cases and the class itself has around 25,000 lines of code which obviously makes it somewhat hard to maintain and read as it's somewhat complex.

What I had in mind and ended up doing is a base class handler that basically has a virtual void in it and takes the data from the desired class (equivalent to previous switch statement cases) and overrides it to run the code.

So yea, I wanted to ask for opinions on this. What's preferable? A switch statement with over 25,000 lines of code which is hard to read/maintain but faster if I'm correct or 300 different classes that will override a base handler when they're called?

Comment: In what world would 25000 lines of code to be maintained by humans be preferable to anything? Especially within a single method. It should be obvious.

Comment: There is repetition in those 25000 lines? If so, that would be target for refactoring. If there is no repetition, split the cases in multiple classes, each handling a branch of the switch (a "strategy"). Then load the strategies onto a dictionary. A Dictionary access is marginally slower than a switch statement, and should have negligible impact when compared with the rest of the code. Could you provide some example (maybe not the whole 25000, but maybe a 1000 like lines?).

Comment: There's no repetition in the 25,000 lines as they are all different an refer to a unique action.
I'm not using a dictionary either to get which class to pick... This is how I'm doing it:

var id = Type.GetType("MyApp.SubFolder.ID_" + _identifier);

var identifier = Activator.CreateInstance(id, _myparam) as MyClass;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 99% of scenarios I recommend maintainability over efficiency. Given that this is C# I will assume that we don't have some hard deadline based loop times or some other mission critical requirement that is usually associated with lower level languages or real time embedded systems.

I will say that a 25,000 line file is un-maintainable and needs to be decomposed. Whether that means to decompose it into a set of virtual classes or use some more traditional decomposition such as trying to abstract pieces with inheritance I could not give you a recommendation without more insight.

(However I usually lean on using inheritance with abstract classes. I rarely find a good use case for virtualization outside of extending generated code)

To answer the initial question, scattering with virtual void is a better solution than a single large switch statement.

Best of luck!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It does make sense and is what I had in mind as well.